# ActiveMQ information about delete of queue

Tags: java, activemq-classic

How can I get to know that queue is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen in on the Advisory Topic: "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Queue"

Take a look at this page:

http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

and specifically the part about destination and message based advisories. There you can see that the topic above informs you about queue creates and destroys

Answer (score 0):

Advisory Topic: "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Queue" doesn't send information about deletion of queue over admin panel.